# Is there a way to have deployment of a .env file while keeping security advantages of environment variables?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm using a .env file to handle logging into sites in my application and have added *.env to my .gitignore for the moment for security. However, this login will be needed for anyone that installs the project so I ​was wondering what the way forward is. Will I have to discard this layer of security?

Answer (score 1):

Include a readme that explains the file needed and where to get the credentials for it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: You shouldn't put credentials in a git repo. Put a template for the file, and include an explanation of where to get the credentials needed.

Comment: Agreed. You could then rather store and share credentials with a shared password manager.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same method of configuring the environment variables for a development environment of my Node.js application. The approach that I have used is that I have explained the overall environment variables in a project wiki—on GitLab. This helps other members of the team to create their own version of a .env file and configure the settings as per their machines.

We have more or less the following configurations,

1. Application Insights instrumentation keys
2. SQL Server connection string, and its parts
3. Configurations for ORMs (delete tables)
4. Current environment settings (production, development, testing)

Of course these settings require a refresh, thus on each platform we either manually create a locally git-ignored .env file, or we use the CI/CD environment settings to control the variables.

On GitLab, for instance, we can have the environment variables created in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which takes care of the variable injections for application to work fine.

> login will be needed for anyone that installs the project

If this login is for something related to production environment, then you need to rethink the overall security of your application. If these credentials are related to development or testing, then your team members can install the same tools and platforms on their own machines too.

Oh, one more thing, addition of .env file will surely cause problems on production when your application will load configurations on startup.